# How to set up the number of inputs neurons in sklearn MLPClassifier?

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network

Given a dataset of `n` samples, `m` features, and using `[sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier][1]`, how can I set `hidden_layer_sizes` to start with `m` inputs? For instance, I understand that if `hidden_layer_sizes= (10,10)` it means there are 2 hidden layers each of 10 neurons (i.e., units) but I don't know if this also implies 10 inputs as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This classifier/regressor, as implemented, is doing this automatically when calling fit.

This can be seen in it's code [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py#L318).

Excerpt:

```python
n_samples, n_features = X.shape

# Ensure y is 2D
if y.ndim == 1:
    y = y.reshape((-1, 1))

self.n_outputs_ = y.shape[1]

layer_units = ([n_features] + hidden_layer_sizes +
               [self.n_outputs_])
```

You see, that your potentially given `hidden_layer_sizes` is surrounded by layer-dimensions defined by your data within `.fit()`. This is the reason, the signature reads like [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.fit) with a subtraction of 2!:

> Parameters
>
> ```
> hidden_layer_sizes : tuple, length = n_layers - 2, default (100,)
>
> The ith element represents the number of neurons in the ith hidden layer.
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your response. So there will be an input layer of `n_features` neurons internally applied+ a single neuron for the ouput!!

Comment: Yes. It's visualized [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html#multi-layer-perceptron).